# Infimum taken over finite coverings

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> For $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, define $J_*(E)=\inf\sum_{j=1}^N |I_j|$, where $I_j$ are intervals and the infimum is taken over all *finite* coverings of $E \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j$. Compute $J_*(E_1)$, $J_*(E_2)$, and $J_*(E_1 \cup E_2)$, where $E_1=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $E_2 = (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]$.

I would like to understand this conceptually. What does the question mean when it says "the infimum is taken over all *finite* coverings"? For $E_1 \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j$, I was thinking, for example, $$E_1=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset [0,1+\frac 1j]$$ as in, $I_j=[0,1+\frac 1j]$.

Comment: Well, it meants that it wants you to consider only finite coverings! There are infinite coverings of the set $E$ by intervals, and you should **not** take these into account when computing the $\inf$.

Answer (score 0):

A finite covering is just that: a finite collection of sets $I_1,...,I_N$ such that $E\subset \cup_{j=1}^N I_j$. Depending on your definitions, the sets $I_k$ are probably required to be open or closed.

In your example $E_1$ is covered by a single element $[0,1+1/j]$ for any $j$.

As an example, suppose that $E_1=[0,1)$. Then $E_1\subset \cup_{j=1}^\infty [0,1-1/j]$, but this is an infinite cover (and cannot be done in a finite way for that particular set and family of covers).

Comment: So, for example, if $I_j = [0,1+\frac 1j]$, then the cover $\bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j$ for $E_1 \cup E_2 = [0,1]$ is also infinite?

Comment: @dragon: Why would it be infinite if you have $N$ sets you're covering with???? Again the definition of a *finite* cover is when you have a *finite* collection of sets $I_k$ whose union contains your set. In the definition of $J_*$ its sort of redundant since they already wrote $\sum_{i=1}^N I_i$

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to type $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty$, not $\bigcup_{j=1}^N$, in my previous comment. Yes, I know that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$ is an *infinite* collection of sets $I_j$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j$ is a *finite* collection of sets $I_j$.